# How to create new collection, using computed data from existing collection mongodb

Tags: java, json, mongodb, mongo-shell

hi am looking  to create a new collection, for that get computed data from existing collection,

Sample data

```
{MID:100,stage:6,
    hustle:[{id:1,name:"jack",level:4,target:10,completedTime:new Date("2015-12-12")},
    {id:1,name:"jack",level:4,target:10,completedTime:new Date("2015-12-12")},
    {id:1,name:"jack",level:4,target:10,completedTime:new Date("2015-12-12")},
    {id:1,name:"jack",level:4,target:10,completedTime:new Date("2015-12-12")},
    {id:82,name:"Mario",level:2,target:8,completedTime:new Date("2015-12-15")},
    {id:82,name:"Mario",level:2,target:8,completedTime:new Date("2015-12-15")},
    {id:82,name:"Mario",level:2,target:8,completedTime:new Date("2015-12-15")},
    {id:82,name:"Mario",level:2,target:8,completedTime:new Date("2015-12-15")}]}
```

Create new collection "Recent_MID" with this data

```
{
    "_id": 82,
    "name": "Mario",
    "level": 2,
    "recentTIme": ISODate("2015-12-15T00:00:00Z"),
    "accessCount": 4
} {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "jack",
    "level": 4,
    "recentTIme": ISODate("2015-12-12T00:00:00Z"),
    "accessCount": 4
}
```

Comment: To create new collection ,Use $out operator at the  end of the aggregate pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/)
operator to create new collection ,while using aggregation

```
    db.mid.aggregate([{
        $unwind: "$hustle"
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: "$hustle.id",
            name: {
                $first: "$hustle.name"
            },
            level: {
                $first: "$hustle.level"
            },
            recentTIme: {
                $first: "$hustle.completedTime"
            },
            accessCount: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    }, {
        $out: "Recent_MID"
    }]).pretty()
```